# Запрет доступа к ресурсам через .htaccess по таймеру

Tags: .htaccess

Мне интересно, можно ли запретить через файл .htaccess доступ к некоторым ресурсам, спустя n-ое количество времени.
Если возможно так сделать расскажите каким образом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В .htaccess можно запретить доступ на основе времени.

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} > 16
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Будет запрещён ([F]) доступ ко всему (.*) если TIME_HOUR > 16

Подробнее [тут есть](http://www.shtogrin.com/library/web/mod_rewrite/examples/time/)